# Nunit tests not running after upgrading from .NET Framework to .NET 5

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, .net-5, visual-studio-extensions

I just upgraded a project from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET 5.0, and now when I open Test Explorer and try to run my NUnit unit tests, they silently do nothing - can't find any logging info either. My environment:

- Visual Studio Pro 2019 16.11.7
- **NUnit 3 Test Adapter** (v. 3.17.0) extension installed
- **NUnit** (v. 3.13.1) nuget package installed in the relevant test project
- TFM for the test project and lib to be tested are both `net5.0-windows`

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Not sure this helps but I have NUnit3TestAdapter and Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk installed as a nuget package and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk NuGet package.